# Google Visualization Chart Data Range

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I have this code,

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", '1', {packages:['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var query = new google.visualization.Query(
      'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ntnhvfMhYtFNwFjkoKu8cUZOQPCaT5_U1Z6piB_w0-E/edit#gid=0');
  query.setQuery('order by A');
  query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }

  var options = {
          title: 'TEMP & HUMID',
    hAxis: {
        direction: -1
        },
    legend: 'none'

      };

  var data = response.getDataTable();
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('columnchart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>

<title>Data from a Spreadsheet</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="columnchart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my spreadsheet data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ntnhvfMhYtFNwFjkoKu8cUZOQPCaT5_U1Z6piB_w0-E

What I want to do is to plot last 5 data. **i.e) row 8 - 12** in my spreadsheet.

I tried the limit and range queries, but what I want to do is, if a new data comes in, I want the chart to refer the updated last 5 data **i.e) row 9 -13**

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is a best approach, but I work it out.

So, before drawing the table, I actually called the spreadsheet in JSON format and retrieve its column length.

Then I subtracted the column length by number of data I want to display (limit query) which will give me offset to start.

Then I made a string with the value of limit and offset to pass the query option to query.setQuery.

Here is the code for the part.

```
function drawChart() {
  var query = new google.visualization.Query(
      'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NSEbUWojJsMzhH0hi8kx8ic7Xxuq29z0c7BXs-inzb8/edit#gid=0');
    $.getJSON("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1NSEbUWojJsMzhH0hi8kx8ic7Xxuq29z0c7BXs-inzb8/od6/public/basic?hl=en_US&alt=json", function(data) {
    colLen = data.feed.entry.length;
    console.log(colLen);
    limit = 4;
    var offset = colLen - limit;
    console.log(offset);
    queryOption = "limit "+limit+" offset "+offset;
    console.log(queryOption);

    query.setQuery(queryOption);
    query.send(handleQueryResponse);
    });
}
```